# issue on database returning empty value , framework spring boot and MySQL , thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

i im working on a simple bookstore web application, back-end with spring-boot  , major issues  , code  seem to  run well  with no error but  the  database is  unable  to  receive the input data from  the  forum  user ,  database only return empty value like (?,?,?),
code below >>

my expected result i wanted  the  given  value  to  be  store at mysql database

`

```
<div class="container my-5 p-5" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <h4 class="text-centre">New Book Register</h4>
    <form class="col-md-4 offset-md-4" th:action="@{/save}"  method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="author" class="form-label">Author</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-check">
            <label for="price" class="form-label">price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price">
        </div>
      <div style="text-align: centre;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
    </form>

back end---------------------
@Entity

@Table(name = "Book")
public class BookEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String price;
    public BookEntity(int id, String name, String author, String price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void set Price(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public Book Entity() {

    }
------------------------------
@Controller

public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
public   String home(){

        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/book_register")
    public   String bookRegister(){

        return "bookRegister";
    }

    @Get Mapping("/Available_Book")
    public String AvailableBook()
    {

        return "AvailableBook";
    }

     @PostMapping("/save")
    public  String addBook(@ModelAttribute BookEntity b){
        service.save(b);
        return "redirect:/Available_Book";
     }


@Service
public class Book Service {
    @Autowired
    private Book Repository repository;

    public void save(Book Entity b){
        repository.save(b);

    }
```

`

Comment: It is not clear your intentions either you want to store an user data to the db, or retrieve it. I. The first case you should use insert statement to add data. In the second case the db should already be filled up.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the form in your HTML is missing the name attribute in the input fields. The name attribute is crucial for sending the form data to the backend server. Without it, the form data will not be mapped correctly to the BookEntity class in your Spring Boot application.

To fix the issue, make sure to add the name attribute to each input field like

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" name="author">
```